# Error while trying to install Weblogic Server 12c

Tags: weblogic12c

I am facing the below error while trying to install weblogic server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QsRt.png). It's showing unable to access or modify the system registry try again in again in admin cmd although i am using cmd in admin mode.

Expecting accurate answers.